# sql sever 2012 setup crashes when invoked using cygwin

Tags: sql-server, windows, cygwin

I'm using CSC agility platform which is hybrid cloud platform, which uses cygwin to run scripts on the VM's it creates.

I have a windows server 2012 standard, in which I have to install SQL server 2012 express, the setup will get invoked using cygwin.

When I execute SQL server setup using "cmd" i.e command prompt, it runs fine. But when I use cygwin, the installation crashes. If install any other software using cygwin, it works fine, the installation doesn't crash. It only happens with SQL server, but the installation goes fine when done using "cmd".

Even if I open "cmd" through cygwin, the problem occurs.

The installer is not corrupt, i have re-downloaded SQL server setup and tried, it still crashes.

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: scenarioengine.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 11.0.2100.60
  Problem Signature 03: 4f35dbe7
  Problem Signature 04: Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure
  Problem Signature 05: 11.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4f35dbe6
  Problem Signature 07: 200
  Problem Signature 08: 179
  Problem Signature 09: ZAGSF01GRLFWVJMY5S0U0HXSJJE2HDT4
  OS Version:   6.2.9200.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
```

[image]

This is the stacktrace of the exception SQL server installer has produced:

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.ChainerInfrastructureException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'tmp'  Key being added: 'tmp' ---> S
ystem.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'tmp'  Key being added: 'tmp'
   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary.Add(String key, String value)
   at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCaptureUnimpersonated(SafeUserTokenHandle userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection tempFiles, String& outputN
ame, String& errorName, String trueCmdLine)
   at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCapture(SafeUserTokenHandle userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection tempFiles, String& outputName, String& e
rrorName, String trueCmdLine)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.Compile(CompilerParameters options, String compilerDirectory, String compilerExe, String arguments, String& outputFile, Int32& nativeRetu
rnValue, String trueArgs)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters par
ameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(String rootPath, Object objectToSerialize, Boolean saveToCache)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(String rootPath, Object objectToSerialize, Boolean saveToCache)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SetCommonFlag(String key, Boolean value)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Setup.Setup.InitializeLogProviders(ServiceContainer context)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Setup.Setup.Run()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Setup.Setup.Start()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Setup.Setup.Main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I just updated cygwin to the latest version, and it worked.